# Returning number of times atoms in one list appear in another list

Tags: scheme, racket

I am working through an introduction to Scheme course and have been stuck on particular problem for a number of hours. The requirement is to write a function that takes two lists of atoms, lat1 and lat2, and returns the total number of times atoms in lat1 occur in lat2.

for example 
             (occurN '(d e f) '(a x b e d g h f e))
would return 4

So far the code I have is

```
         (define occurN
          (lambda (lat1 lat2)
           (cond 
           ((null? lat1) 0)
           ((null? lat2) 0)
           (else
              (cond
              ((eq? (car lat1) (car lat2)) (add1 (occurN lat1 (cdr lat2))))  
              (else (occurN lat1 (cdr lat2))))))))
```

this obviously works for going through the first element of lat1, checking to see if every element of lat2 is equal to it and adding a 1 to the count if they are, otherwise moving on to the next element. The problem I'm having is getting the code to start on the next value of lat1 and all following values of lat1 while retaining the count and going through the list of lat2 and checking equivalence with the other values of lat1 other than the first, further adding to the count if they are . 
If anyone has any hints as to how I can proceed with this problem it'd be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hint: First write a function to count the occurrences of *one* atom in a list of atoms. Then use that function in the function that solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have `count` which returns the number of times an element occurs in a list:

```
(define (occurN lat1 lat2)
  (apply + (map (lambda (elt1) 
                  (count elt1 lat2)) 
                lat1)))
```

Recognizing the need for `count,` as one step in producing `occurN,` it an important step in decomposing a problem.

Here is a tail-recursive `count`:

```
(define (count elt lst) ; predicate is eq?
  (let counting ((lst lst) (n 0))
    (if (null? lst)
        n
        (counting (cdr lst)
                  (if (eq? elt (car lst))
                      (+ n 1)
                      n)))))
```